# How to change name's item of sortable always

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a *sortable* that it was loaded from JSON files.

Now I want to edit one item for example Little birds.

How to change this?

The HTML code of the *sortable*:

```
<div id="sortparam">

<ul style="" class="ui-sortable" id="sortable">
    <li style="" id="1" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Singular sensation</li>
    <li style="" id="2" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Beady little eyes</li>
    <li style="" id="3" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Little birds </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: For starters, IDs cannot be numbers according to the HTML spec.

Comment: For example how to edit Little birds with Javascript

Comment: @Diodeus they can be since HTML5 - http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @Mirko Cianfarani you're gonna have to explain what you want a bit better than you are ATM...

Comment: This is a sortable's jquery http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
But I want to edit one item. The item before is inserted from the user.
Looking the http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ for example I want Item 3.
How?

Comment: How to edit the item's sortable using the variable???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contenteditable` - http://jsfiddle.net/Jv5Zq/

Click on *"Little birds"* and feel free to edit

```
<div id="sortparam">

<ul style="" class="ui-sortable" id="sortable">
    <li style="" id="1" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Singular sensation</li>
    <li style="" id="2" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Beady little eyes</li>
    <li style="" id="3" class="ui-state-default" contenteditable> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Little birds </li>
</ul>

</div>​
```